# sub returns incorrect data

Tags: regex, r

I have the following chunk of code:

```
temp <- "44C"
sub("^([-+]?[0-9]+)([CF])$","\\2",temp)
```

This correctly returns **C**.

Yet when I try out

```
temp <- "44"
sub("^([-+]?[0-9]+)([CF])$","\\2",temp)
```

I was expecting an empty vector. Instead I get "**44**".

Am I reasoning something wrong?

Comment: To be exact, `sub()` returns exactly what it is supposed to return, but it doesn't behave as one might expect :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `\2` in your second case.So it cannot replace anything and returns the original string unaltered.
When a regex fails in sub then the original string is returned.

Comment: I tend to agree with @joris-meys's reasoning. I was expecting a different answer.

Comment: I now understand your reasoning (which makes sense). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It will work if you add `?` to your regex:

```
temp <- c("44C", "44")
sub("^([-+]?[0-9]+)([CF])?$","\\2",temp)
# [1] "C" ""
```